# How to implement the function similar to ByteBuffer in Java in object-c

Tags: objective-c, bytebuffer

```
private ByteBuffer mBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 60);
        mBuffer.put(data, beginIndex, remain);
```

How do you implement similar functionality in object-c

Comment: You probably want `NSMutableData` but it would be good if you were to describe (in the question) what exactly `ByteBuffer` is and does. That is, don't (just) ask for something "similar to ByteBuffer", ask for the thing you need more generally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry there is no thing similar to ByteBuffer in Objective-c , but there is a good thing you may like it:

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
char *pData = {0x1, 0x2, 0x3};
NSData *secondData = [NSData dataWithBytes:pData length:3];
[data appendData:[secondData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 2)]];
```

Comment: "ByteBuffer" probably operates more like a C array which is available to objective-c.  The OP can calloc, memcpy, address with array notation etc, as well as bridge copy those bytes into NSData or NSString.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am currently using NSMutableData